# Exporting c3.js chart as pdf

Tags: javascript, d3.js, canvas, svg, c3.js

I am using c3.js library for building charts. And I was wondering if there is an easy solution to export charts drawn by c3.js in pdf format.

I got a solution in angular js but I am looking for a jQuery based solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a SVG to PNG and a PNG to PDF converter. Here's a pure JS solution (works with jQuery)

[svg->png](https://github.com/exupero/saveSvgAsPng)

[pdf exporter](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)

Include the two files above in your page. Then use these functions to do your thing:

```js
/**
 * @param {SVGElement} svg
 * @param {Function} callback
 * @param {jsPDF} callback.pdf
 * */
function svg_to_pdf(svg, callback) {
  svgAsDataUri(svg, {}, function(svg_uri) {
    var image = document.createElement('img');

    image.src = svg_uri;
    image.onload = function() {
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var doc = new jsPDF('portrait', 'pt');
      var dataUrl;

      canvas.width = image.width;
      canvas.height = image.height;
      context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
      dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
      doc.addImage(dataUrl, 'JPEG', 0, 0, image.width, image.height);

      callback(doc);
    }
  });
}

/**
 * @param {string} name Name of the file
 * @param {string} dataUriString
*/
function download_pdf(name, dataUriString) {
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    link.href = dataUriString;
    link.download = name;
    document.body.removeChild(link);
  }, false);
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
}
```

Note: Code snippet is entirely copied from [here](https://github.com/haochi/svg_to_pdf/blob/master/svg_to_pdf.js).

Comment: I am trying PDF Exporter link demo in IE and it's not working at all. Any idea?

Answer (score -2):

I have this at the bottom of my page

```
<script>
  function printDiv(divName) 
  {
    // fix weird back fill
    d3.select('#'+divName).selectAll("path").attr("fill", "none");
    //fix no axes
    d3.select('#'+divName).selectAll("path.domain").attr("stroke", "black");
    //fix no tick
    d3.select('#'+divName).selectAll(".tick line").attr("stroke", "black");
    // fix text going off the export (becuase my labels font size is larger than default)
    d3.select('#'+divName+"> svg").style("font-size","12px");
    // add any other styles needed
    var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
    window.print();
    window.location.reload();   
  }
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="printDiv('chart')" value="print a div!"/>
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific in your answer, and relate more to the initial question.

Comment: How does it generates a PDF file (as asked in the question?). To me, it seems just to send it to the printer hopping to delegate this job, but you don't even know if the user has a configured printer in its machine, do you?

Comment: whenever you run "window.print();" it will open a print menu where you can save as pdf/print to pdf.